# Sed script - Removing lines

Tags: regex, sed

I need help with my sed script. I have a XML-file where I have to remove everything except the text enclosed in these tags:

```
<TEXT>......</TEXT>
<HEADLINE>......</HEADLINE>
```

How do I write the sed code ? I know how to remove everything except the text enlosed in ONE tag.

```
s/.*<TEXT>\(.*\)<\/TEXT>.*/\1/
```

But how do i write the sed code for many tags ?

Comment: Why not just use an XML parser?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple commands to `sed`:

```
$ echo '<TEXT>Hello</TEXT>
<HEADLINE>there</HEADLINE>' | sed -n 's/.*<TEXT>\(.*\)<\/TEXT>.*/\1/gp; s/.*<HEADLINE>\(.*\)<\/HEADLINE>.*/\1/gp' 
Hello
there
```

But you really should be careful when applying regex to XML-like files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have valid XML:

```
sed '/.*<\(TEXT\|HEADLINE\)>\(.*\)<\/\(TEXT\|HEADLINE\)>.*/!d;s//\2/' yourfile.xml
```

If you want to use a *sed* script add this line:

```
/.*<\(TEXT\|HEADLINE\)>\(.*\)<\/\(TEXT\|HEADLINE\)>.*/!d;s//\2/
```

Then run:

```
sed -f yourscript.sed < yourfile.xml
```

Comment: But how do add this to a script file ?

Comment: @mrjasmin I added that part to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r '/<(text|headline)>/I!d;s//&\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;:a;/<\//!{$!{N;ba}};s/\n/ /g;s/<\//\n&/;P;D' file
```

This removes all text accept that which is between `TEXT` and `HEADLINE` tags and on multi-line values replaces newlines with spaces.